# Não exibe a string, em C

Tags: c, array, string, char

Estou tendo problemas para copiar string em C, isso não quer funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count;
    char str1[20] = "Hello World", str2[20];
    for(count = 0; str1[count]!='\0'; count++)
        str2[count] = str1[count];
    str2[count] = '\0';
    printf("%c%", str2[count]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Já tentei com %c, e %s, e com chaves no for, mas não aparece nada na tela, %s aparece (null), sei que há a opção de usar o strcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas de por

```
printf("%s\n", str2);
```

`str2[count]` é um caracter, especificamente o `'\0'` que acabaste de lá meter.

Comment: Não precisa do [count]?

Comment: `str2[count]` é um caracter, especificamente o `'\0'` que acabaste de lá meter.

Answer (score 1):

Se for mostrar só um caractere da sequência é "printf("%c", str2[n])". Mas se quiser mostrar todo o texto do array é "printf("%s", str2)".